# How to Convert English to Cron?

Tags: parsing, nlp

I did some searching but haven't landed anything that looks useful yet but I am wondering if anyone knows of something (tool,lib etc) that can parse English phrases and translate them into a cron string.

For example: `Every Tuesday at 15:00` converts to `0 15 * * 2`

It seems like something that would have lots of gotchas and it would be preferable to benefit from someone elses work. You see it in a few nice sites/apps that can work out what you mean from a simple phrase rather than having some hideous user interface.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This sounds like you're looking for an existing program, making this a ServerFault question, not a programming question.

Comment: Not with tags like "nlp" and "parser" and "parse". Definitely a programming question.

Comment: tool, library, framework - I'm not picky. For background I'd like it to generate cron strings for cron and eventually Quartz.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Ruby there's ["Whenever"](http://github.com/javan/whenever) which might provide a starting point: It translates quasi-english (actually it's valid Ruby) into cron strings.

Comment: From your post I was inspired by Whenever and did a little PHP library: https://github.com/bpolaszek/natural-cron-expression

Answer (score 5):

Though this is an old question I would like to list out all libraries/tools that I know so far, so that this answer might help others who arrive on this page looking for the same thing:

**JavaScript:**

- `natural-cron.js` ([link](https://github.com/darkeyedevelopers/natural-cron.js))
- `friendly-cron` ([link](https://github.com/jkriss/friendly-cron))

**PHP:**

- `natural-cron-expression` ([link](https://github.com/bpolaszek/natural-cron-expression))

**Ruby:**

- `whenever` ([link](https://github.com/javan/whenever))

Feel free to reply in comments, if you know about any other library which is not listed here :)

(**Full disclosure:** natural-cron.js has been developed by me & my friend, when no other library satisfied the needs of our project)

Answer (score 1):

Depending on how flexible you need it to be, and how willing to roll up your own sleeves you are, you could define a simple grammar for this.

**Every** would be a quantifier. You may need others but I can't think of any. Valid syntax might be:

**Every** *(day-spec)* **AT** *(time)*

Where *day-spec* could be a literal day (ie. **Monday**) or be a day of the month (ie. **30th Day**) or some other syntax (I'd suggest fortnights but I'm not sure if Cron can represent those well).

Time could be specified using either 24 hour (**16:00**) or 12 hour (**4:00pm**) format.

Another syntax that you might want is:
**Every** *(frequency)* **From** *(time*) where frequency is basically *(quantity)* *(unit)* (ie. **10 Minutes**). The from time enables you to set an offset (eg. **Every 30  Minutes From 01:10am**).

You'd probably need to sit down and figure out these details a bit more. But a rigid grammar could be implemented relatively easily using [recursive descent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursive_descent_parser).

Comment: Defining a grammar for this would be over the top. There's nothing recursive about this grammar. Making a small statemachine is the fastest route

Comment: @reinier It wouldn't be SO if there wasn't the "roll your own hammer" for the "how to crack a walnut?" question. :)

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, about those gotchas... How about also writing one that translates the cron params *back* to English?  That way you can see if the parser "understood" you.

Comment: I saw a lot of stuff that translates cron to English whilst searching and had the same thought. Obviously you'd not always get the same English back out the other end since there's a many-to-one from English to cron. Still a nice idea. Rather reminds me of the fun that can be had translating phrases to and from foreign languages using google translate.